# How can I load application bundle-embedded JSON into an AppleScript?

Tags: json, applescript

I had found this Q&A ([Can and how do you get remote data (e.g. JSON) into AppleScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601149/can-and-how-do-you-get-remote-data-e-g-json-into-applescript)), and have started to use JSON Helper.

## JSON Data

```
{
  "prop1": "text",
  "prop2": [
    {
      "prop3": "text",
      "prop4": "text"
    }
  ]
}
```

## Sample Program Code

```
-- set configPath to path to resource "config.json"
set configPath to POSIX path of (path to resource "config.json")
-- set configPath to "file://" & POSIX path of (path to resource "config.json")

set configOptionsString to (read POSIX file configPath)

tell application "JSON Helper"
    -- set configOptions to fetch JSON from configPath
    set configOptions to read JSON from configOptionsString
    -- set configOptions to make JSON from configOptionsString
end tell

-- display dialog configPath as string
display dialog configOptionsString
display dialog configOptions
display dialog configOptions as string
```

## Results

`configPath` correctly display the '/'-based, POSIX path.
`configOptionsString` correctly contains the JSON text.
`configOptions` incorrectly is empty.

### Approach #1

The only problem is, while trying to use the `fetch JSON from` command, I cannot coerce it to use a local file path and get the text/JSON content I expect.

I have tried both the HFS- and POSIX-style file paths, including POSIX with `file://` prepended to it, resulting in this format (`file:///...`).  I also got around any alias errors (HFS paths I think) by appending `as string` to the command, for example when debugging viewing the path through a `display dialog` instruction.

I know it can find the resource as I am using this: `path to resource "config.json"`.  It had an error about not finding the resource until I restarted the Script Editor.

### Approach #2

I have even tried to load the file's contents normally, and parse them as a string using the `read JSON from` command as such:

```
set configOptionsString to (read POSIX file configPath)

tell application "JSON Helper"
  set configOptions to read JSON from configOptionsString
end tell
```

### Approach #3

For completeness sake, I have tried to take that same string and run it through the `make JSON from` command, just to try it, but it also produces empty output.

## Question

Is JSON Helper ([Examples](http://www.mousedown.net/mouseware/JSON_Examples.html)) capable of doing this, and if so, how, or should I try using a tool such as [applescript-json](https://github.com/KAYLukas/applescript-json) instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JSON Helper is capable to do this, not approach #1 – it affects `http` URLs only – nor #3 – it creates a JSON string from an AppleScript dictionary `{foo : "bar"}`, not vice versa – , but approach #2.

The issue of approach #2 is most likely the kind of file path (or corrupted JSON).

The AppleScript `read` command accepts the following forms:

- POSIX path (slash separated) - `read "/Users/myUser/json.txt"`
- AppleScript alias specifier - `read (path to resource "json.txt")`
- HFS path (colon separated) with prefix `file` - `read file "Macintosh HD:Users:myUser:json.txt"`

Comment: I did try to highlight that I did get paths to work, and tried varying combinations to be sure.  Just checked the JSON data via QuickLook on a mac, and it did have a syntax error :).  Missed a comma after one of the properties.  After a quick fix, save the file, and restart the script editor to be sure, `read` and `make` still do not produce any string content besides emptiness.

Comment: I tested it successfully with 3 different JSON files. Approach #2 is supposed to work. By the way: The JSON Data is not valid JSON, all keys must also be wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to support old OS X versions, use Cocoa's `NSJSONSerialization` class via the AppleScript-ObjectiveC bridge, which has been a native feature in AS since 10.10.